# Empty reCAPTCHA token flutter with firebase

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I send the user a password reset email with this code:

```
Future passwordReset() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email: _emailController.text.trim());
            showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(content: Text("Email sent successfully!"),);
            });
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e) {
      print(e);
      showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(content: Text(e.message.toString()),);
      });
    }
  }
```

But in the console I get:

```
I/FirebaseAuth(22362): Password reset request email@gmail.com with empty reCAPTCHA token
D/NetworkSecurityConfig(22362): No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/System  (22362): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/LocalRequestInterceptor(22362): Error getting App Check token; using placeholder token instead. Error: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: No AppCheckProvider installed.
I/System.out(22362): [okhttp]:check permission begin!
I/.app(22362): The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/System.out(22362): [okhttp]:not MMS!
I/System.out(22362): [okhttp]:not Email!
I/System.out(22362): [socket]:check permission begin!
```

How can I add reCAPTCHA to my app?